# In-app purchase failed while verifying receipt

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftystorekit

In my application I have 3 consumable in-app purchases. I have tested them in sandbox environment and they work as expected. I use the `SwiftyStoreKit` framework for in-app purchases.

The following code is used to perform the purchase.

```
func purchase(_ purchase: String, quantity: Int = 1, completion: @escaping ((_ result: PurchaseDetails?)->Void)) {
        ProgressIndicatorManager.shared.show()

        SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(purchase) { (result) in
            ProgressIndicatorManager.shared.dismiss()
            if case .success(let purchase) = result {
                // Deliver content from server, then:
                if purchase.needsFinishTransaction {
                    SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchase.transaction)
                }
                completion(purchase)
            } else {
                completion(nil)
            }
            if let alert = self.alertForPurchaseResult(result) {
                self.showAlert(alert)
            }
        }
    }
```

Once the purchase is completed I verify the receipt.

```
    /// This function is use for verify receipt
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - purchase: purchase identifier
    func verifyPurchase(_ purchase: String, completion: @escaping (VerifyPurchaseResult) -> Void) {
        ProgressIndicatorManager.shared.show()
        verifyReceipt { result in
            ProgressIndicatorManager.shared.dismiss()
            switch result {
            case .success(let receipt):
                let purchaseResult = SwiftyStoreKit.verifyPurchase(
                    productId: purchase,
                    inReceipt: receipt)
                self.showAlert(self.alertForVerifyPurchase(purchaseResult, productId: purchase))
                completion(purchaseResult)
            case .error:
                self.showAlert(self.alertForVerifyReceipt(result))
            }
        }
    }
```

In sandbox everything works fine. However, the Apple review team reported that they are getting the error shown in the attached screenshot.
[image: error screenshot]

Comment: It looks like your code is just throwing whatever came back from the validation server into an alert if there is a validation error. In this case it seems to be a 404 not found for whatever URL was requested. What web page is it trying to access?

Comment: @Paulw11 i am passing product identifier in verify purchase string for verification.